# File I/O with MPI

Tags: c, image-processing, mpi

I want to read PPM file tile by tile by different processors using MPI. I am planning to do it by first creating MPI_Subarray specifying tile and image size. and then MPI_SetView. But what should be the header size of ppm file?

Is my approach correct for reading it tile by tile, please let me know most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: PPM files aren't generally arranged tile by tile, so trying to read one tile by tile is going to be a whole lot more inefficient than reading it line by line...

Comment: You don't know the header size a priori; you'll have to read in the header manually, outside of MPI-IO; you will need to do that in general to get the image size anyway.  Then you'll know the size of the header and can set the offset appropriately in MPI_File_set_view().